# android cursor indicates row count 1 but throws exception 0 rows found

Tags: android, sqlite

Have you ever had a cursor tell you that it has data but immediately throw an exception when trying to access that data? No? I have and I am at my wits end.
Blow is the code that throws an exception. Below it I will add the Log Cat output.

```
protected void setValue(String qVal) {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(qVal,"|");
    String first = tokenizer.nextToken();
    if(first.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        return;
    String searchID = tokenizer.nextToken();
    String [] cols = {TempImageEntry.RawData, TempImageEntry.FileName};
    String selection = TempImageEntry.ID + "=" + searchID;
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getReadableDatabase().query(TempImageEntry.TABLE_NAME,cols,selection,null,null,null,null);
    boolean check = cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(!check)
    {
        cursor.close();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Could not find image data!");
        return;
    }
    int temp1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TempImageEntry.FileName);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Count:"+count);
    String FName = cursor.getString(temp1);
    byte [] rawData = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(TempImageEntry.RawData));
    cursor.close();
    setImageData(rawData,FName);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"parsed image data");
}
```

Loggat output:

`D/ImageHelper: Count:1
E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 2 columns.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e94ac8)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

I've tried a clean rebuild of the code. nothing helps.
I extracted the database from the device, opened it in SQLite browser, entered the same query being generated by android, and I got back data.
Every other cursor in the app follows this exact same logic path and they all work. 
I even took some variables out of inline into temp to see what they look like during runtime.

Thanks for any advice you can give

Comment: `Have you ever had a cursor tell you that it has data` It's not your case: `a CursorWindow which has 0 rows` tells you that your Cursor is **empty**.

Comment: I bet that blob column is to big for CursorWindow ...

Comment: On sqlite >= 3.7.6 check blob length ... with `SELECT length(blob_column)` compare it with `Resources.getSystem().getInteger(
                com.android.internal.R.integer.config_cursorWindowSize)` * 1024 (i'm not sure if you can get this value - you can just assume that it is something about 1MB) ... if it's bigger then use `SELECT substr(blob_column, start, len)` in the loop for getting blob partially ... **or as it was written multiple times do not store blob in the sqlite itself but just save a file(fx with FileProvider from compat lib) and store only a path to it**

Comment: So you're saying that the blob is too big?  Would that cause the app crash when trying to even read the string which contains the blob name?

Comment: As I wrote "I bet" ... to check if I'm right change `cols = {TempImageEntry.RawData, TempImageEntry.FileName};` to `cols = {TempImageEntry.FileName};` and comment out getting blob data and replace `setImageData(rawData,FName);` with `setImageData(null,FName);` ... if it would work (or crash later with NPE in `setImageData`) then the problem is with blob size .... alos I'm not getting *when trying to even read the string which contains the blob name?* if blob 1column is in the query then you are both name and blob even if you don't use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help.
Turns out the cursor window does indeed not allow data greater than 1 MB in a query.
Bellow is the code that now pulls out the file in bits and pieces.

```
private byte[] ProcessRawData(String searchID) {
    String selection = TempImageEntry.ID + "=" + searchID;
    String [] cols;
    int count = 0;
    byte [] rawData = new byte[0];
    Long tracker = BlobSize;//use a generic length function of your choice
    do {
        cols = new String [] {"substr(" + TempImageEntry.RawData + ","+(1 + 1000000L * count)+",1000000)"};
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getReadableDatabase().query(TempImageEntry.TABLE_NAME,cols,selection,null,null,null,null);
        if(!cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            cursor.close();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Serious Error");
            return rawData;
        }
        byte [] theBit = cursor.getBlob(0);//get the current chunk
        cursor.close();
        byte[] c = new byte[rawData.length + theBit.length];//make room for the new chunk
        System.arraycopy(rawData, 0, c, 0, rawData.length);//copy old chunk into the new room
        System.arraycopy(theBit, 0, c, rawData.length, theBit.length);//copy the new chunk into the room made for the total
        rawData = c;//set the new collected as the main
        count++;
        tracker -= 1000000L;
    }while (tracker> 1000000L);
    cols = new String[]{"substr(" + TempImageEntry.RawData + "," + (1 + 1000000L * count) + "," + tracker + ")"};
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getReadableDatabase().query(TempImageEntry.TABLE_NAME, cols, selection, null, null, null, null);
    if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Serious Error");
        return rawData;
    }
    byte[] theBit = cursor.getBlob(0);
    cursor.close();
    byte[] c = new byte[rawData.length + theBit.length];
    System.arraycopy(rawData, 0, c, 0, rawData.length);
    System.arraycopy(theBit, 0, c, rawData.length, theBit.length);
    rawData = c;

    return rawData;
}
```

Maybe no the best way of doing this but it's functional.
Yes storing blobs is maybe not the best way of doing this since we can write to disk but I've experienced problems with android with files going missing and we want to explicitly destroy files when they are no longer needed.